# Google Maps API -> When embedding a map in a page, do we have the option to use, "What's here"?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I just got a request to create a page and the creator of this request wants to be able to use the, "What's here" functionality that you see when you right click somewhere on the map when you are visiting the www.maps.google.com.

I haven't seen an example of this anywhere.  I just want to make sure that prior to be saying that this can be done that it truly can be.

If it is possible I would really appreciate a link to an example, etc.

Thanks for any advice direction on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't actually get a built-in right-click menu that includes an option: **What's here?**, but you can use the [Places Service/Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) to implement very similar functionality.